# How can I get ItemAttachment content bytes to save mail attachments?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In EWS you can get the bytes of an Item like this:

```
var theBytes = _att.Item.MimeContent.Content;
```

The equivalent of this in Microsoft Graph API is `contentBytes` but that is only available for `FileAttachment`, how do I get the `contentBytes` for `ItemAttachment`?